# Java - Optimal way to overwrite values from a subset JSON document to a superset JSON document

Tags: java, json

I have the below superset JSON and a subset JSON. In my java code, I need to parse the superset JSON and for every element in the propList which has overwrite flag set to true, I need to read the value from subset JSON which has a similar structure as superset JSON and overwrite it.

What is the optimal way to achieve this in java? The JSON document can be quite big.

**Superset JSON:**

```html
{
  "configList": [
 {
   "configElement": "elem1",
   "propList": [
  {
    "property": "prop1",
    "value": "val1",
    "overwriteValueFromSubset": false
  },
  {
    "property": "prop2",
    "value": "",
    "overwriteValueFromSubset": true
  },
  {
    "property": "prop3",
    "value": "val3",
    "overwriteValueFromSubset": false
  }
   ]
 },
 {
   "configElement": "elem2",
   "propList": [
  {
    "property": "prop1",
    "value": "val1",
    "overwriteValueFromSubset": false
  },
  {
    "property": "prop2",
    "value": "val2",
    "overwriteValueFromSubset": false
  },
  {
    "property": "prop3",
    "value": "",
    "overwriteValueFromSubset": true
  }
   ]
 }
  ]
}
```

**Subset JSON:**

```html
{
  "configList": [
    {
      "configElement": "elem1",
      "propList": [
        {
          "property": "prop2",
          "value": "new_value",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "configElement": "elem2",
      "propList": [
        {
          "property": "prop3",
          "value": "new_value",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can fit all data in memory. Google "how to convert Java POJO to JSON object", (and vice versa). So the answer (without actually coding it for you) is convert it into a big Java object (graph), and process the POJOs, then then just call whatever method saves it back out as JSON. The Jackson libraries are what you want here. The object is called a 'mapper'. That should be enough tips to get you going.

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/